# Statistical analysis of .h5 files (SPSS?)

Tags: python, r, hdf5, statistics, h5py

I have two sets of data in separated .h5 files (Hierarchical Data Format 5, HDF5), obtained with python scripts, and I would like to perform statistical analysis to find correlations between them. My experience here is limited; I don't know any R.

I would like to load the data into SPSS, but SPSS doesn't seem to support .h5. What would be the best way to go here? I can write everything to a .csv file, but I would loose the names of the variables. Is there a way to convert the data without loosing any information? And why doesn't SPSS support h5 anyway?

I am aware of the existence of the Rpy module. Do you think it is worthwhile to learn programming in R? Would this give me the same arsenal of methods as I have in SPSS?

Thank you for your input!

Comment: You can do statistical analysis directly in python using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), which also supports HDF out of the box using [pytables](http://pytables.org/).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to convert the data without losing any information?

If the HDF5 data is regular enough, you can just load it in Python or R and save it out again as CSV (or even SPSS .sav format if you're a bit more adventurous and/or care about performance).

> Why doesn't SPSS support h5 anyway?

Who knows.  It probably should.  Oh well.

> Do you think it is worthwhile to learn programming in R?

If you find SPSS useful, you may also find R useful.  Since you mentioned Python, you may find that useful too, but it's more of a general-purpose language: more flexible, but less focused on math and stats.

> Would R give me the same arsenal of methods as I have in SPSS?

Probably, depending on exactly what you're doing.  R has most stuff for math and stats, including some fairly esoteric and/or new algorithms in installable packages.  It has a few things Python doesn't have (yet), but Python also covers most of the bases for many users.

Comment: That's a very strong claim about feature parity of R and Python which can be easily reverted in other direction.